# PowerShell Invoke-Webrequest / provide password and skip promt

Tags: powershell, credentials, powershell-4.0

I made a script accessing an API which requires authentication. The this is working if I enter the credentials (email+pw) into the prompt:

```
$cred = Get-Credential 
$web = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $srcURI -Credential $cred
```

But this does not allow me to automate this setup, as a prompt is always coming up asking for Username/PW.

I tried several different ways, but none seems to be working:

For me the most logical was:

```
 $username="user" 
 $password="password1"

 $PScredOBJ = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password) 
 $cred2 = Get-Credential -Credential $PScredOBJ
```

Result: Still an empty prompt showing up.

Anybody knows how to handle this?

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been covered in a lot of places, a google search would give an answer. [Here's](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714574.aspx) the first one I found using "automate ps credential" as my search terms. To reiterate:

```
$password = "password" | ConvertTo-SecureString  -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential "username",$password
```